# ggplot: heatmap based on two vectors

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to plot data as a heat map in `ggplot2`. I understand that you'd normally have to have `x`, `y`, and `z` coordinated to plot `x` against `y` and then color by `z`. I have found plenty of heat map examples but they all already have the `z` vector.

I don't understand how I get from having two columns in a data.frame  to producing a useable z vector. In my case, each row would represent the data from one person and each column is a score on a scale (or whatever). Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(x = sample(20, 500, prob=c(1:10, 10:1), replace = TRUE), 
                y = sample(20, 500, prob=c(1:10, 10:1), replace = TRUE))
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile()
```

This produces the tiles but how do I get `d$z` so I can set `geom_tile(aes(fill=z))`?

I feel like this should be really simple but I can't wrap my head around it. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds that you want something else than a heatmap. The z axis determine the color of your tiles. So in your example what do you want to determine the color of your tiles?

Comment: The tile at, for example, [3, 7] should be colored according to how often the values 3 and 7 co-occur. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could for instance compute the number of observations for each combination of x and y and map this to `fill`:

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(x = sample(20, 500, prob=c(1:10, 10:1), replace = TRUE), 
                y = sample(20, 500, prob=c(1:10, 10:1), replace = TRUE))

library(dplyr)
group_by(d,x,y) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y,fill=n)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I need. I have a really hard time parsing the `dplyr` syntax, though.